# Unity detect user touch relative to player position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, touch, unity3d-2dtools

This is all being done on a 2D Unity game.

I'm trying to create a Vector2 that represents where the user is touching their screen relative to the players position. This is being done with the use of two other Vector2's, one being the players position and the other being the touch position. For some reason, though, I'm actually detecting where the user is touching relative to the bottom left corner of the screen. The code is fairly simple:

```
Vector2 Begin;
Vector2 CurTouch;
Vector2 Vec;
...
void Update()
{
    foreach(Touch t in Input.Touches)
    {
        if(t.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) do something with Vec
        else
        {
            Begin = transform.position;
            CurTouch = t.position;
            Vec = CurTouch - Begin;
        }
    }
}
```

There is absolutely nothing in the bottom left corner of the screen. I can move the player around and Begin still is put in the bottom left corner. I've tried using the position of different components of the player that I know for certain are where I want them to be, still bottom left corner.

transform.position is actually used elsewhere in Update() to reset the player standing up if they fall over, I move them up 1 unit and reset their eulerAngles to 0 and that code chunk works perfect, but for some reason it only wants to set Begin = to the bottom left corner of the screen.

I used to set Begin = t.position if t.phase == TouchPhase.Began, which worked beautifully, but I decided I would rather have Begin = player's position which is not working out too well right now.

EDIT: I've started trying to set Begin to the transform.position of EVERYTHING (Starting platform, Main Camera, different colliders, etc.) and Begin simply will not be anything except the bottom left corner of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Touch.position is in screenspace. 
Use Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint to transform to Worldspace.

Reference:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html